# How to do alphanumeric validation for a particular column (say $2) of a file using awk?

Tags: awk

How do I perform alphanumeric validation for a particular column (say `$2`) of a file using awk?

For example I've tried:

```
awk -F, '{if ($10==(/[0-9a-zA-Z]/)) count+=1;} END {print count}' final.csv
```

I don't get any errors or a result.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work:

```
awk -F, '$10 ~ /^[[:alnum:]]+$/ { count++ } END{ print count+0 }'
```

Comment: Please underline that you are using GAWK. Original AWKs do not have `[:alnum:]` and friends.

Comment: @yeti Yes they do. Any Posix compliant `awk` knows this..

Comment: +1. I also prefer `print count+0` to report a zero count when no matches are found (nothing is printed in this situation when `print count` is used

Answer (score 3):

You can maybe do:

```
awk '$10 ~ /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/ {count++} END{print count}' file
```

This also works to me: to check from `0` to `z`, being all numbers and letters in the range.

```
awk '$10 ~ /^[0-z]+$/ {count++} END{print count}' file
```

The idea is to check if the given field (`$10` in your case) is just based on a set of alphanumeric characters. This is accomplished by using `^` and `$` to indicate the beginning and the end of the field.

Comment: Without explicitly setting the locale, there's no way to know what is in the range `[0-z]` or `[0-9]`. Consider using a POSIX character class instead.

Comment: I see, @ChrisDown but `[[:alnum:]]` is not working to me either.

Comment: @fedorqui:`[:alnum:]` is a GAWK feature. Non-GNUish AWKs do not have that. GNU tends to stuff lotsa features into each utility and often users of such GNUtilities forget to mention that they are NOT using the classical utilities with the same name. GNU causes lots of such confusion...

Comment: @yeti: that is not correct, see the other comment..

Comment: @fedorqui I think there should be a `+` sign instead of a `*` Otherwise empty fields count as alphanumeric

Comment: @yeti `[:alnum:]` _is_ POSIX, not GNU. It is described in the official [POSIX regex docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html).

Comment: @terdon there is no need to specify `+` instead of `*`, because as `FS=" "` (default) a field will never be empty.

Comment: True but since the OP is actually using `-F,` it won't work for them without `+`.

Comment: @terdon fair enough! You are right.